# speed up computing large loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to prepare a look up table for HD video processing, My code is fine but it is taking very long to compute , I am new in Matlab and i don't know is it possible to speed up processing for this loop,

```
while a<1024
   while b<1024
      while c<1024
         while d<1024
            while e<1024

               Result=xx; %by formula

               f1(result,e+1)=bitor(f1(result,e+1),16);
               f1(result,d+1)=bitor(f1(result,d+1),32);
               f1(result,c+1)=bitor(f1(result,c+1),64);
               f1(result,b+1)=bitor(f1(result,b+1),128);
               f1(result,a+1)=bitor(f1(result,a+1),256);

               e=e+1;
            end

            e=0;
            d=d+1;
         end

         d=0;
         e=0;
         c=c+1;
      end

      d=0;
      e=0;
      c=0;
      b=b+1;
   end

   d=0;
   e=0;
   c=0;
   b=0;
   a=a+1;
end
```

Comment: You could do the same using [`for`-loops](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/07/19/how-for-works/) (`for a=0:1024`), which would be much cleaner imho. For real speed up considerations, you need to share the `result = xx formula`.

Comment: As @JandeGier said if you work on the _formula_ you might even could remove the _loops_.

Comment: thanks guys, this is a process to find a pattern , and it's necessary to pass this loops, the (result=xx) formula is different by applications and it's not fixed,

Answer (score 0):

You need to pre-allocate your f1 object (`f1 = zeros(size(Result,1),1024)` or if it is a function pre-allocate whatever data storage it is referring to the total size it will be.

Otherwise the time taken to traverse the loops will increase exponentially (because it is copying the already assigned data at each loop).

I refer you to: [Techniques for Improving Performance](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html?s_tid=doc_12b)

Comment: thanks Hans, i'd pre-allocated  f1 before, "f1=zeros(256,1024,'uint16')", i think maybe there is not any way to speed-up this process, i want to prepare a look up table and it is possible for me to prepare it by another software, whats your suggestion which software suitable to do that.